# Jquery selecting a nested element inside the next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

from the structure below I am trying to place a class on the span that follows the button but I cant seem to traverse into the div containing the span.

I can target the div fine using:

```
$("button").next('div').addClass('alert');
```

But can't get that class applied to the span directly using:

```
$("button").next('div > span').addClass('alert');
```

or

```
$("button").next('div').next('span').addClass('alert');
```

My example structure is

```
<button>Click</button>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
<button>Click</button>
  <div>
    <span></span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to add class to `span` where `button` is clicked you need to handle `click event` of `button`

```
$(function () {
  $("button").click(function () {
     $(this).next('div').find('span').addClass('alert');
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply - yes I am aware of the click event i was just more focusing on the method to traverse inside the div. The find method in your example and others is what i needed - thank you all for your help - as Leopard was the first to provide this method and I can only apply 1 correct answer I will apply to him but thanks to you all

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [find](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function.

Please try this:

```
$("button").next('div').find('span').addClass('alert');
```

```js
$("button").next('div').find('span').addClass('alert');
```

```css
.alert{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
  <div>
    <span>abc</span>
  </div>
<button>Click</button>
  <div>
    <span>def</span>
  </div>
```

Another solution is to use [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) method.

```js
$("button").next('div').children('span').addClass('alert');
```

```css
.alert{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
  <div>
    <span>abc</span>
  </div>
<button>Click</button>
  <div>
    <span>def</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").next('div').find('span').addClass('alert');
```

```css
.alert{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click</button>
<div>
  <span>this</span>
</div>
<button>Click</button>
<div>
  <span>this</span>
</div>
```

This should work. use `.next()` with `.find()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
$("button").on('click',function(){
 $(this).next('div').find('span').addClass('alert');
})
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/hyd35fz0/)

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, next() traverses siblings:

```
.next( [selector ] )
Description: Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set 
of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling 
only if it matches that selector.
```

So you need to be using children() instead.